# pgfplot does not scale y-axis correctly

Tags: pgfplots

I use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={solid},
        every tick/.append style={semithick,color=black}, 
    }


    \begin{axis}[smooth,
    scale only axis = true, width = 0.9\textwidth, height = 0.35\textwidth,
    scaled ticks = false,
    minor tick num =0,
    thick,
    ymin =0, ymax =0.7, xmin =0,  xmax=70, 
    grid style ={dashed},
    ylabel = {x}, 
    xlabel={y},
    grid = both
    ]

    \addplot [only marks, mark = o, mark size = 3pt,error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
%       (2,0.5) += (0,0.09) -= (0,0.05)
%       (4,0.4) += (0,0.09) -= (0,0.05)
%       (6,0.3) += (0,0.09) -= (0,0.05)
%       (8,0.2) += (0,0.09) -= (0,0.05)
%       (10,0.1) += (0,0.09) -= (0,0.05)
%       (12,0) += (0,0.09) -= (0,0.05)
        (0,0.5827757) += (0,005946691) -= (0,005760857)
        (2,0.091987874) += (0,0.061325249) -= (0,0.091987874)
        (4,0.153313123) += (0,0) -= (0,0)
        (6,0.191612033) += (0,0.023026339) -= (0,0.015390053)
        (8,0.194196622) += (0,0.02044175) -= (0,0.010220875)
        (10,0.235080121) += (0,0.010220875) -= (0,0.02044175)
        (12,0.265742746) += (0,0.010220875) -= (0,0.02044175)
        (14,0.296405371) += (0,0.040883499) -= (0,0.02044175)
        (16,0.33728887) += (0,0.030662625) -= (0,0.030662625)
        (18,0.358969514) += (0,0.012698663) -= (0,0.021680644)
        (20,0.394654199) += (0,0.022742784) -= (0,0.026702704)
        (22,0.418072041) += (0,0.011204702) -= (0,0.019457922)
        (26,0.439497618) += (0,0.02044175) -= (0,0.010220875)
        (28,0.439497618) += (0,0.051104374) -= (0,0.040883499)
        (30,0.447028789) += (0,0.012910579) -= (0,0.017752046)
        (32,0.464681011) += (0,0.009483286) -= (0,0.004741643)
        (38,0.480381118) += (0,0.010220875) -= (0,0.02044175)
        (40,0.490601993) += (0,0.061325249) -= (0,0.061325249)
        (42,0.500822867) += (0,0.051104374) -= (0,0.040883499)
        (44,0.511043742) += (0,0.040883499) -= (0,0.051104374)
        (46,0.531485492) += (0,0.051104374) -= (0,0.040883499)
        (48,0.572368991) += (0,0.010220875) -= (0,0.02044175)   


    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The output is just a flat line, because the y-scale is too large. If I use the coordinates which are in comment right now, it works fine.

What am I missing? Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: With "real" values, not working]
[image: With example vaules, working]

Comment: The error bars at `x=0` are wrong, you're missing the `0.` at the start of the y-values. It should read `(0,0.5827757) += (0,0.005946691) -= (0,0.005760857)` instead of `(0,0.5827757) += (0,005946691) -= (0,005760857)`

Comment: @Jake, do you want to write an answer or shall we close the question as solved in the comments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a typo only.

Comment: Should I delete it? Or can I close it somehow?